# Regex: match text between two strings not including my string

Tags: regex

I have a string and want to match:

```
await Listing.find({
    Test: 1
});
```

But don’t want to match it if it ends with `.lean();`

```
await Listing.find({
    Test: 1
}).lean();
```

I have this regex but it’s not working:
`(?<=await)([\S\s]*?)(?!.+\.lean())(;)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this modified regex:

```
(?<=await)([\S\s]*?)(?<!.+\.lean\(\))(;)
```

All I have changed is:

Making `\.lean` a negative look BEHIND

ESCAPING the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

```
^await(?:(?!\.lean\(\)).)*;$
```

##### Short Explanation

- `^await` String starts with `await`
- `(?:(?!\.lean\(\)).)*;` Contains anything except `.lean()` till the last `;` colon

Also, see the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CsXhyF/3)

##### JavaScript Example

```js
let regex = /^await(?:(?!\.lean\(\)).)*;$/s;

console.log(regex.test(`await Listing.find({
    Test: 1
});`));

console.log(regex.test(`await Listing.find({
    Test: 1
}).lean();`));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay between a single opening and closing parenthesis, you don't need any assertion:

```
\bawait\s[^()]*\([^()]*\);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Faew3N/1)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this in vscode to find all mongoose queries that don't use lean so that I can increase the speed of queries and reduce memory footprint:

```
await (.*)find(([^;]|\n)*?)(?<!.\.lean\(\))(;)
```